# Attach public ip to nic base on parameter like public or privateonly with multiple VM'S

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

How to attach public ip based on parameter privateonly or public, trying to create it with multiple vms. I am giving here full template which i am running.

```
  {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for the resources."
      }
    },
    "vmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "vm",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "ClusterType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "3 vm apache",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Type of cluster to deploy, this is using a single storage account"
      }
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "centos",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "User name for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminPasswordOrKey": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Size for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "storageNewOrExisting": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "new"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat('storage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the storage account"
      }
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage account type"
      }
    },
    "storageAccountResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the resource group for the existing storage account"
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkNewOrExisting": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "new",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Determines whether or not a new virtual network should be provisioned."
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "VirtualNetwork",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the virtual network"
      }
    },
    "addressPrefixes": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        "10.0.0.0/16"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Address prefix of the virtual network"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "default",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the subnet"
      }
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet prefix of the virtual network"
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the resource group for the existing virtual network"
      }
    },
    "vmDataDiskSize":{
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "50",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Minimum data disk size should be 50 GB"
      },    
    "publicIpName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "rxnode",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of public IP Address"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "publisher": "OpenLogic",
    "offer": "CentOS",
    "sku": "7.3",
    "version": "latest",
    "vmBootDiskSize": 50,
    "nicName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '-nic-')]",
    "numberOfVM": "[int(first(parameters('ClusterType')))]",
    "apacheinstallation": "[contains(parameters('ClusterType'), 'apache')]",
    "networkSecurityGroupName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '-nsg-ssh')]",
    "publicIpName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'-publicip')]"
    "privateIp": {
      "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
      "subnet": {
          "id": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
      }
    },
    "copy": [
      {
          "name": "publicIPAddress",
          "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]",
          "input": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',  concat(variables('publicIpName'), copyIndex('publicIPAddress')))]"
          }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('storageNewOrExisting'), 'new')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "Storage",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('publicIpName'), 'None')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "name": "[concat(variables('publicIpName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "ipLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "Basic"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
      }
    },
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('virtualNetworkNewOrExisting'), 'new')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefixes')]"
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "default-allow-ssh",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 1000,
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "destinationPortRange": "22",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "allow-webport-8080",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 1200,
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "destinationPortRange": "8080",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(variables('nicName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "nicLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "ipLoop",
        "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
        "[variables('networkSecurityGroupName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": "[if(equals(variables('publicipName'), 'None'), variables('privateIp'), union(variables('privateIp'), variables('publicIPAddress')[copyIndex()]))]" }
        ],
        "networkSecurityGroup": {
           "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "nicLoop"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex())]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]",
          "linuxConfiguration": {
            "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
            "ssh": {
              "publicKeys": [
                {
                  "path": "[concat('/home/', parameters('adminUsername'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
                  "keyData": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('publisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('offer')]",
            "sku": "[variables('sku')]",
            "version": "[variables('version')]"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "diskSizeGB": "[variables('vmBootDiskSize')]"
          },
          "copy": [
            {
              "name": "dataDisks",
              "count": 1,
              "input": {
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('vmDataDiskSize')]",
                "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '-datadisk', copyIndex(), copyIndex('dataDisks'))]",
                "createOption": "Empty"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(variables('nicName'), copyindex()))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('storageAccountResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2018-02-01').primaryEndpoints.blob]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
}
```

Here I am putting json context into if condition. If needs to attach public ip then it will pass json context to publicIPAddress else it will pass null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `union()` function with predefined variables to achieve that. a lot cleaner + I'm not sure your way will work with all the escapes (i think you are not allowed to build real json with `json()` function; at least whatever I tried - failed).

```
"variables": {
    "publicIP": {
        "publicIPAddress": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',  concat(variables('publicIpName')))]"
        }
    },
    "privateIp": {
        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
        "subnet": {
            "id": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your ipConfigurations you can do this:

```
"ipConfigurations": [
    {
        "name": "ipconfig1",
        "properties": "[if(equals(variables('publicipName'), 'None'), variables('privateIp'), union(variables('privateIp'), variables('publicIp'))]"
    }
],
```

this will use privateIp variable when no public IP is needed and it will add public IP when its needed.

EDIT: if using copyIndex with publicIp you need to do this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {
        "name": "testo",
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "publicIPAddress",
                "count": 3,
                "input": {
                    "publicIPAddress": {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',  concat(variables('name'), '-ip-', copyIndex('publicIPAddress')))]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "privateIp": {
            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
            "subnet": {
                "id": "resourceId"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "name": "[concat(variables('name'), '-ip-', copyIndex())]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "ipLoop",
                "count": 3
            },
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[concat(variables('name'), copyIndex())]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "ipLoop"
            ],
            "copy": {
                "name": "nicLoop",
                "count": 3
            },
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": "[union(variables('privateIp'), variables('publicIPAddress')[copyIndex()])]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. 
The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified.

Comment: ah, right. that means you need to turn it into a copy and reference array index. I'll be at my laptop in about 3 hours and can show you how if you can't figure it out

Comment: No issue will find solution.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: same error with updated answer.The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified.

Comment: made a typo, otherwise this is working, you probably forgot to edit something in

Comment: replaced "count": "[something]" to "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]"  and  defined "copy" in variable section of ARM template. do we need to edit anything else.

Comment: i have no idea what you've done wrong, here's a working example, without an `if()` clause, i'm sure you can edit it in

Comment: please accept this answer :)

Comment: its giving an error.
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:58:40 - Resource 
Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces 'vm-nic-1' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequestFormat",
    "message": "Cannot parse the request.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InvalidJson",
        "message": "Could not find member 'id' on object of type 
'NetworkInterfaceIpConfigurationProperties'. Path 
'properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.id'."
      }
    ]
  }
}'

Comment: I've just tested it, it works. please consider copypasting properly

Comment: updated full template code in quetion.

Comment: look, this is not a code writing service, you asked a question, i've showed you how to achieve that what you are asking. if you want help integrating this into your existing template - raise a new question. you have a sample repro template that shows a working solution

Comment: check your other question, please