# Condition statement not working for vm extensions

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

condition statement in for azure vm extension is not working. I have to create execute extension block based on number of vm provide in variable. I am creating multiple vm with this template.
I have tried below code with condition but no luck. i want execute block based on numberofvm variable value. full template code is below.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for the resources."
      }
    },
    "vmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "vm",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "ClusterType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "3 vm apache",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Type of cluster to deploy, this is using a single storage account"
      }
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "centos",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "User name for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminPasswordOrKey": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Size for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "storageNewOrExisting": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "new",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Determines whether or not a new storage account should be provisioned."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat('storage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the storage account"
      }
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage account type"
      }
    },
    "storageAccountResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the resource group for the existing storage account"
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkNewOrExisting": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "new",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Determines whether or not a new virtual network should be provisioned."
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "VirtualNetwork",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the virtual network"
      }
    },
    "addressPrefixes": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        "10.0.0.0/16"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Address prefix of the virtual network"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "default",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the subnet"
      }
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet prefix of the virtual network"
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the resource group for the existing virtual network"
      }
    },
    "vmDataDiskSize":{
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "50",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Minimum data disk size should be 50 GB"
      }    
    }

  },
  "variables": {
    "publisher": "OpenLogic",
    "offer": "CentOS",
    "sku": "7.3",
    "version": "latest",
    "vmBootDiskSize": 50,
    "nicName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '-nic-')]",
    "numberOfVM": "[int(first(parameters('ClusterType')))]",
    "apacheinstallation": "[contains(parameters('ClusterType'), 'apache')]",
    "networkSecurityGroupName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '-nsg-ssh')]",
    "publicIpName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'-publicip')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('storageNewOrExisting'), 'new')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "Storage",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "name": "[concat(variables('publicIpName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "ipLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "Basic"
      },    
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
      }
    },
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('virtualNetworkNewOrExisting'), 'new')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefixes')]"
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "default-allow-ssh",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 1000,
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "destinationPortRange": "22",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "allow-webport-8080",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 1200,
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "destinationPortRange": "8080",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
            }
          },          
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(variables('nicName'), copyindex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "nicLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "ipLoop",
        "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
        "[variables('networkSecurityGroupName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', concat(variables('publicIpName'), copyIndex()))]"
              },
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "networkSecurityGroup": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "nicLoop"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex())]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]",
          "linuxConfiguration": {
            "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
            "ssh": {
              "publicKeys": [
                {
                  "path": "[concat('/home/', parameters('adminUsername'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
                  "keyData": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('publisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('offer')]",
            "sku": "[variables('sku')]",
            "version": "[variables('version')]"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "diskSizeGB": "[variables('vmBootDiskSize')]"
          },
          "copy": [
            {
              "name": "dataDisks",
              "count": 1,
              "input": {
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('vmDataDiskSize')]",
                "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '-datadisk', copyIndex(), copyIndex('dataDisks'))]",
                "createOption": "Empty"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(variables('nicName'), copyindex()))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('storageAccountResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2018-02-01').primaryEndpoints.blob]"
          }
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "condition": "[equals(variables('numberOfVM'), 3)]",
          "name": "config-app-3",
          "type": "extensions",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "dependsOn": [
             "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 0))]",
             "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 1))]",
             "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 2))]",
           ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "config-app-3"
          },
          "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
            "type": "CustomScript",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "protectedSettings": {
              "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0/install_apache.sh')]"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "condition": "[equals(variables('numberOfVM'), 5)]",
          "name": "config-app-5",
          "type": "extensions",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "dependsOn": [
             "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 0))]",
             "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 1))]",
             "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 2))]",
             "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 3))]",
             "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmName'), 4))]",
           ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "config-app-5"
          },
          "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
            "type": "CustomScript",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "protectedSettings": {
              "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0/install_apache.sh')]"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
   }
  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
}
```

I am getting below error while deploying.
 'The template reference 
'vm-nic-3' is not valid: could not find template resource or resource 
copy with this name. Please see 
https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.'.

Comment: does this not work for you?

Comment: no this is not working

Answer (score 2):

this error has nothing to do with your condition, it is happening in some other place where you reference the resource you call `vm-nic-1`. it doesnt exist, so most likely called something else.

ok, looking at your template, i think I understand what you are trying to do, you are trying to apply different extensions depending on the case in your template. but conditions work after template was evaluated, hence you are getting this error (as with the case of 3 vms, only nics 0,1,2 are being created, its looking for nics 3 and 4 as well). easiest way of fixing this is moving extension to a separate resource and depending on the vmloop, so it wont care how many vms are created, it will also create 1 extension for every vm. if you want different things to happen inside the extension you can use `if()` functions in the template to define them.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex())]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "nicLoop"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
            "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex())]",
            "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
            "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "publisher": "[variables('publisher')]",
                "offer": "[variables('offer')]",
                "sku": "[variables('sku')]",
                "version": "[variables('version')]"
            },
            "osDisk": {
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "createOption": "FromImage",
                "diskSizeGB": "[variables('vmBootDiskSize')]"
            },
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "dataDisks",
                    "count": 1,
                    "input": {
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('vmDataDiskSize')]",
                        "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '-datadisk', copyIndex(), copyIndex('dataDisks'))]",
                        "createOption": "Empty"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(variables('nicName'), copyindex()))]"
                }
            ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
            "bootDiagnostics": {
                "enabled": true,
                "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('storageAccountResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2018-02-01').primaryEndpoints.blob]"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "condition": "[equals(variables('numberOfVM'), 3)]",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex(), '/config-app-3')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "dependsOn": [
        "virtualMachineLoop"
    ],
    "copy": {
        "name": "extensionLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfVM')]"
    },
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "config-app-3"
    },
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "protectedSettings": {
            "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0/install_apache.sh')]"
        }
    }
}
```

ps. I've remowed non working part from the VM definition and your script extension definition is wrong as well.

Comment: error updated in quetion please see updated error. this gives an error if we define both blocks. If we define one block it work fine. It is looking dependency of 'vm-nic-3' .

Comment: well, it doesnt really matter. these resources do not reference that resource. so its some other resource that's referencing it. i suggest you show the whole template.

Comment: updated my quetion with full template code.please help me to solve.

Comment: no updated error in thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473535/attach-public-ip-to-nic-base-on-parameter-like-public-or-privateonly-with-multip/54474255?noredirect=1#comment95765414_54474255

Comment: i need private ip of each vm then only application can configure. so that i have defined  extension outside loop.after creating all vms we can configure app.

Comment: ok, how does this not work with my template (which does work, compared to yours) :)